# Change button border color on click (android button maker)

Tags: android, button, android-studio

Ive generated android button styles online on android button maker but now i would like the button border to change on click. To make sort of feedback to the user see they clicked the button.

Ive tried with the button state selector with 2 diferent xml button files but it gave me a error.

Hope someone has a easy fix.
Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more information. How did you try to use state selector? What is the exact error message? etc. Maybe you should read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: `it gave me a error.` ... **Which** error?

Comment: I havent saved it and now already went back to the latest working version. but the app crashed on launching. I tried using a selector for when the button was pressed, to use another xml layout file

Comment: @DerGolem  But do you know any easy way of changing the color on click?

Comment: @Gumbo But do you know any easy way of changing the color on click?

Comment: Yes: using a StateList Drawable. Whic seems to be what you tried. Unfortunately you didn't post any xml, so it's hard to tell what is wrong.

Comment: @DerGolem now i have my drawable button file on android:background, where should i put the statelist drawable file?  Thanks <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMapa"
        android:text="Mapa"
        android:onClick="btnMapaClick"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowRadius="5"/>

Comment: Correct. `android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"` So, the StateList is `/res/drawable/buttonshape.xml`

Answer (score 0):

A some people said the answer was to create a selector.
I've managed to make it work! Thanks everybody!